# Glitch can't "read property 'value' of ...html:18 null"?

Tags: javascript, html, iframe, glitch-framework

So I'm working on a website with the [Glitch Framework](https://glitch.com). I have a script that I want to create an iFrame when the user connects to the webpage. The script has a variable that reads from an `<input>` block, then sets the iFrame link to the variable plus the rest of the link. The input and script are on separate pages, so here are the two pages:

index.html

```html
<body>
 <label for="puServNm">Server name:</input>
 <input type="text" id="puServNm" name="puServNm">
 <button onclick="connectPublic()">Connect</button>
 <!-- connectPublic() redirects you to 'connect-public.html' -->
</body>
```

connect-public.html

```html
<body>
 <script type="text/javascript">
  var connectPub = document.getElementsByName("puServNm")[0].value;
  var iframe = document.createElement("iframe");
  document.body.appendChild(iframe);

  iframe.src = "https://" + connectPub + "-uc.glitch.me";
 </script>
```

When I access `connect-public.html` after filling out the input and then clicking connect nothing loads. I open up the console and it says "`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of undefined at connect-public.html:18`"

What have I done wrong, or need to fix? If this exact same question has been asked, please link me to it- it'd be greatly appreciated.

Comment: How are the two files connected? Are you trying to access a Dom Node from another document? That will not work, i guess...

Comment: Yes, `puServNm` does not exist in the new webpage. You'll have to pass the data along with the redirect using a query parameter or bring the logic to create an iframe from the other HTML document into the current one. But I'm not entirely sure what you're going for beyond that.

Comment: Okay, let be me as specific as possible. When the user inputs, say "helloworld", then press 'Connect', the button references `connectPublic()` in script.js (which is the only code in the file). `connectPublic()` consists of only a `window.location.href = '...'`. Then the `<script>` loads. I think that moving the entire iFrame creation to script.js would work, but I don't know how to make it only load on that page and not index.html. Maybe that's my problem.